# Position div ontop of active select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu which I want to position ontop of everything else. However if I click on a select and then hover over my dropdown menu the select options appear ontop of the menu. How can I get the hovered menu to appear ontop of the select?

[image]

Sample code

http://jsfiddle.net/b2vak/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy fix would be to hide / show the select input on hover. Like this:

```
$("#menubar ul > li").hover(function() {
    $("#menu").show();
    $("select").hide();
}, function() {
    $("#menu").hide();
    $("select").show();
});
```

However I think this is not a very good solution, but the only one I can come up with :/

Comment: I think it's a valid solution.  I thought of the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any other way. As long as the select box is opened, it is going to be on top.

Comment: Yeah. I thought of the same solution but didn't think it was a very great one. I was hoping just playing with z-index could fix it :-(

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is with an iframe in the background. You can look at Stu Nicholls' example: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/iframe-shim.html

or just do a google search: http://www.google.at/search?q=css+selectbox+iframe and you will find plenty of examples.

This is the only way, I know of, to do this cross browser.